# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on windows 8

Tags: java, windows

When I am trying to run a jar file by giving the following command

```
java -Xmx500m -jar ap.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

I am getting the following error. I am using windows 8

```
Throwable Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/supercsv/prefs/CsvPreference
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/supercsv/prefs/CsvPreference
        at bc.c.Util.process(Util.java:135)
        at bc.m.TabularReader$CSVReader.<init>(TabularReader.java:68)
        at bc.m.TabularReader.<init>(TabularReader.java:37)
        at bc.c.Spread2db.main(Spread2db.java:244)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/supercsv/prefs/CsvPreference
        at bc.m.TabularReader$CSVReader.<init>(TabularReader.java:64)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.supercsv.prefs.CsvPreference
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
```

Please help me resolving this exception.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to download the SuperCSV jar and also place it on your classpath.

http://sourceforge.net/p/supercsv/news/2014/04/super-csv-220-released/

The library you're using (ap.jar) is referring to this other SuperCSV library.
So you need the SuperCSV jar on your classpath too.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/supercsv/files/

Comment: Please tell me the meaning of placing the SuperCSV  jar placing in the class path

Comment: See the answer from Reimeus, that's what it means basically. Also run `java -help` and note these flags: `-cp` and `-classpath`.

Comment: When I am following @Reimeus process I am getting the following error:

`Error: Unable to access jarfile ap.jar;super-csv-2.0.1.jar`

Comment: Then use the `-classpath` option. Read in general what a classpath is in Java. Do some reading, then the error will get fixed easily.